# PHP OOP use extends class in functions

Tags: php, oop

Here's my current code

```
class Database {
    //Connect to database here...
}

class User extends Database {

    public function GetUInfo($id) {
        $db = new Database;
        $db->query("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `id`=:id");
        $db->bind(":id", $id);
        return $db->single();
    }

    public function uptime($id) {
        $db = new Database;
        $db->query("UPDATE `users` SET `time`=".$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']." WHERE `id`=:id");
        $db->bind(":id", $id);
        return $db->execute();  
    }

}
```

In the `User` class, how can I make it so that `$db = new Database;` is ready in all of the public functions, instead of having to add `$db = new Database;` in each of the functions?

Comment: can we show Database code class ? as you have extends User class from Database

Comment: @AnandPatel - SO won't let me show it because it's rather large and it'd make the post majority code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have extends Database Class into User why you are creating objects ? 
you can directly access functions(public and protected) of Database Class

you can directly access it using `$this` keyword.

only you have to make connection in Constructor(parent class) and in child class you have to call parent class constructor.

```
<?php
class Database
{
    protected $db;

    public function __construct()
    {
        //your connection code
    }
}

class User extends Database
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function GetUInfo($id)
    {
        $this->query("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `id`=:id");
        $this->bind(":id", $id);
        return $this->single();
    }

    public function uptime($id)
    {
        $this->query("UPDATE `users` SET `time`=".$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']." WHERE `id`=:id");
        $this->bind(":id", $id);
        return $this->execute();
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: If you want to unit test this kind of code you're stuck with your database. IMHO is it better to push the database dependency inside the user class. Not saying your approach it's a bad thing *per se*, just keep it in mind :-)

Comment: as he have extends Database class to User that`s why ;) otherwise i dont post this answer

Answer (score 2):

Create a constructor and private property `$db`

```
private $db;

public function __construct() {
  $this->db = new Database();
}
```

So you can use it like this

```
   public function uptime($id) {
        $this->db->query("UPDATE `users` SET `time`=".$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']." WHERE `id`=:id");
        $this->db->bind(":id", $id);
        return $this->db->execute();  
    }
```

As metioned `mTorres` its better to do like this

```
public function __construct(Database $db) { $this->db = $db; }
```

If you are new to OOP - [read this article](http://www.phptherightway.com/#object-oriented-programming) it might help.

Comment: This works, but I wonder if there's an easier option to avoid having to use $this->db. It's fine, but it'd be nice just to be able to use $db->

Comment: Yes, but you could make the dependency explicit and inject it instead of creating a new object directly: ```public __construct(DatabaseType $db) { $this->db = $db; }```

Comment: @mTorres totally agree with you

Comment: @BryanParmenter, there's no other way, even if you extend your db (which is probably not a good idea), you MUST use ```$this->db```, think that in order to type ```$db``` it must be a local (for the method!) variable, you could easily do ```$db = $this->db``` at the beginning of each method (but if you have a good IDE that shouldn't bother you)

Comment: Thank you. I'm still new to OOP and this has been very helpful.